# How does write take advantage of the format arguments contained in a simple-error

Tags: common-lisp

I am curious how

```
(write 
  (make-instance 'simple-error 
                  :format-control "A:~a ~% B:~a~%" 
                  :format-arguments `("A" "B"))
   :stream nil)
```

works, as I tried to implement it myself to gain experience in basic lisp funcionality but soon had to realize, that I am not able to. As the intuitive way of implementation:

```
(defmethod my-write ((simple-error err))
   (FORMAT nil (if (simple-condition-format-control err)
                   (simple-condition-format-control err)
                   "")
               (simple-condition-format-arguments err)))
```

obviously cannot work, as `(simple-condition-format-arguments err)` returns the list of arguments and therefore, in the example above, "B:~a" does not have a corresponding parameter to print.

So how would I actually implement this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_apply.html) for this.  It takes the function passed as its first argument and applies it to arguments constructed from its other arguments.  For example, `(apply #'f 1 2)` calls `(f 1 2)`, `(apply #'f 1 '(2 3))` calls `(f 1 2 3)` and so on.  It's perfectly suited for this situation.

SBCL has [a function](https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/fd210120f575183fbb5493a7ebc6b32aab107466/src/code/condition.lisp#L590) almost identical to yours:

```
(defun simple-condition-printer (condition stream)
  (let ((control (simple-condition-format-control condition)))
    (if control
        (apply #'format stream
               control
               (simple-condition-format-arguments condition))
        (error "No format-control for ~S" condition))))
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Samuel, you need to use `APPLY`.

Also note that `NIL` for the stream in `WRITE` does something else than in `FORMAT`. With `FORMAT` the stream argument `NIL` causes the output to be returned as a string. With man other output functions, like `WRITE`, it means *standard output*.